# Umbraco Forms Validation Error Showing Incorrect Validation

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-forms

Umbraco Forms Installed working as expected 90% of the time, validating correctly.

There is an intermittent issue where the validation is firing incorrectly and preventing the form from submitting.

We have a simple contact form.

- Name (*required text)
- Email (*required email)
- Phone
- Message (*required text)
- Recaptcha (*required)

When working the above validation all fires as expected. However the intermittent issue is that even when all fields are populated with correct data the Name, Email and Message are returning a  validation error saying 'Please enter valid email address'. Even though the email address is valid and the Name & Message field is not being validated as an email.

[image: Example of errored validation]

The site is hosting on an Azure App Service.

Restarting the App Service in Azure resolves the issue and the form works correctly for a period of time before this happens again.

This is setup as per my other Umbraco sites which use Umbraco Forms and I do not experience this issue.

Anyone got any pointers on where I could look to debug/resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded UmbracoForms to the latest version and this seems to have resolved the issue.